# Passing query parameters to React Apollo POST requests

Tags: react-apollo, apollo-client

Is there a way to configure React Apollo to pass default query string parameters to each query / mutation ?

For now, all my requests have this format : 
`POST https://domain:8000/graphql`;

I would like to have something like :
`POST https://domain:8000/graphql?query=queryName`

This would help for quick debugging purposes in the Chrome DevTools panel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement a [custom fetch](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/networking/advanced-http-networking/#custom-fetching) that apollo's http-link will then use.

When instantiating apollo client, do the following:

```js
const customFetch = (uri, options) => {
  const { operationName } = JSON.parse(options.body);
  return fetch(`${uri}/graph/graphql?opname=${operationName}`, options);
};
const link = createHttpLink({ fetch: customFetch });
```